# When I go to second page in codeigniter pagination, header file not adding, UI changes

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, pagination

When I click on 2 page in pagination link, it does not include header.php file on 2 page result, all css are in header.php, so how can I keep my header in all links in pagination.

**dashboard.php**

```
<?php if(!empty($userexpense)){ ?>
<table class="table table-responsive table-hover table-bordered">
<tr>
<th>Sr.No</th>
<th>Expense Detail</th>
<th>Expense Date</th>
<th>Amount</th>
</tr>
<?php foreach ($userexpense as $value) {?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $value->expense_id; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $value->expense_detail; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo date('d-m-Y',strtotime($value->expense_date)); ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $value->amount; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
<tr class="success">
    <td colspan="2" style="visibility: hidden"></td>
    <td><?php echo "Total"; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $userexpense_total; ?></td>
</tr>
</table>
<p><?php echo $links; ?></p>
<?php }else{ ?>
<div class="well well-lg">You have not yet expensed Anything For This Month</div>
<?php } ?>
```

**mainController.php** index()

```
$config = array();
        $config["base_url"] = base_url() . "mainController/index";
        $config["total_rows"] = $this->expense_model->record_count($session_data['id']);
        $config["per_page"] = 2;
        $config["uri_segment"] = 3;
        $this->pagination->initialize($config);
        $page = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;
        $data["userexpense"] =     $this->expense_model->get_user_expense($config["per_page"],     $page,$session_data['id']);
        $data["links"] = $this->pagination->create_links();
$data['userexpense_total'] = $this->expense_model->get_user_expense_total($session_data['id']);


        $data['title'] = "Dashboard";
        $this->load->view('template/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('dashboard', $data);
        $this->load->view('template/footer');
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried loading your header and footer via the main dashboard view, rather than inline like this? CI loads views as a final action. Try loading your header and footer into your $data array and passing those to your dashboard view, like this:

#### In mainController.php

```
$data['header'] = $this->load->view('template/header', true);
$data['footer'] = $this->load->view('template/footer', true);

$this->load->view('dashboard',$data);
```

You may need to get a little creative with the data you're passing in so things don't get mixed up. You could also load your header and footer directly in your dashboard.php View file like so (as it will have all your $data).

#### In dashboard.php

```
$this->load->view('template/header', true);
$this->load->view('template/footer', true);
```

Comment: I solved the problem by adding base_url() when adding css and js files. Css and js files were not loading. Now it is working fine. :)

Comment: You could probably save yourself the trouble of doing that by leading your source path with a forward slash (e.g. /css/mystyles.css vs css/mystyles.css)